# Debian 7.11 (wheezy) and PHP 7.0

Tags: debian, php

I have a Debian 7.11 (wheezy) installed as a development server and I attempted an upgrade from PHP 5 to 7. I got as far as `php -v` returning 7.2.2 but the last obstacle after a long installation process was that I am unable to enable PHP 7 in Apache2.

I have attempted to install `libapache2-mod-php7.0` via `apt-get` and this returns an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libapache2-mod-php7.0'
```

I even attempted downloading the `.deb` file from packages.debian.org but this returns an error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: archive 'libapache2-mod-php7.0_7.0.28-1_amd64.deb' contains 
not understood data member control.tar.xz, giving up
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php7.0_7.0.28-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0_7.0.28-1_amd64.deb
```

I basically can't run `a2enmod php7` for Apache to enable PHP. What can I do here?

Comment: Any chance you could upgrade to Debian 9? It includes PHP 7 as standard...

Comment: I have root access so I could technically perform an upgrade. I have very little stuff running there atm so I might pull it off without too many problems.

Comment: Well, I successfully upgraded from wheezy to jessie and managed to install PHP 7 without any bigger problems. Everything works now.

Comment: So now you're successfully in Debian oldstable (Debian 8 = jessie) as opposed to oldoldstable (Debian 7 = wheezy). One more upgrade would bring you to the *current* stable version, Debian 9 (stretch). The full support of jessie is ending in June of this year, however there is Long Term Support after that for two more years. With Debian 9, there is full support to year 2020 and Long Term Support until 2022. See https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases

Comment: Yes, I know. This was the first time I upgraded the distro myself and after this was done step two was upgrading Stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend upgrading to Debian 9 if you can, it includes PHP 7 as standard.

Comment: yes, this is my plan now. First step was wheezy => jessie, and after fixing a few things in Apache and installing PHP 7 it worked, so now I'm planning on upgrading jessie => stretch. Thank you!